Angular PWA Version Compatibility
I'm trying to add a PWA support to my existing Angular project (non-standalone) but it seems to have compatibility issues. This is how the package.json looks like.
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node -r dotenv/config envPopulator.js && ng serve -o",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/common": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/core": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/router": "^17.3.0",
    "@tsparticles/angular": "^3.0.0",
    "@tsparticles/engine": "^3.4.0",
    "@tsparticles/slim": "^3.4.0",
    "@types/dom-to-image": "^2.6.7",
    "angularx-qrcode": "^17.0.1",
    "canvas-confetti": "^1.9.3",
    "dom-to-image": "^2.6.0",
    "dom-to-image-more": "^3.3.0",
    "driver.js": "^1.3.1",
    "ngx-spinner": "^17.0.0",
    "primeflex": "^3.3.1",
    "primeicons": "^7.0.0",
    "primeng": "^17.18.4",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.7.5",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^17.3.4",
    "@angular/cli": "^17.3.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.3.0",
    "@types/canvas-confetti": "^1.6.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "@types/uuid": "^10.0.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "jasmine-core": "~5.1.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.4.2"
  }
}

ng version of my machine
     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 18.1.3
Node: 20.13.1
Package Manager: npm 10.5.2
OS: win32 x64

Angular:
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.1801.3 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/core         18.1.3 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics   18.1.3 (cli-only)
@schematics/angular          18.1.3 (cli-only)


I tried ng add @angular/pwa,
ℹ Using package manager: npm
✔ Found compatible package version: @angular/pwa@17.3.8.
✔ Package information loaded.

The package @angular/pwa@17.3.8 will be installed and executed.
Would you like to proceed? Yes
✔ Packages successfully installed.
CREATE ngsw-config.json (667 bytes)
CREATE src/manifest.webmanifest (1395 bytes)
CREATE src/assets/icons/icon-128x128.png (2875 bytes)
CREATE src/assets/icons/icon-144x144.png (3077 bytes)
CREATE src/assets/icons/icon-152x152.png (3293 bytes)
CREATE src/assets/icons/icon-192x192.png (4306 bytes)
CREATE src/assets/icons/icon-384x384.png (11028 bytes)
CREATE src/assets/icons/icon-512x512.png (16332 bytes)
CREATE src/assets/icons/icon-72x72.png (1995 bytes)
CREATE src/assets/icons/icon-96x96.png (2404 bytes)
UPDATE angular.json (5497 bytes)
UPDATE package.json (1669 bytes)
UPDATE src/app/app.module.ts (6077 bytes)
UPDATE src/index.html (1838 bytes)
⠸ Installing packages (npm)...npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: client@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/core@17.3.9
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!   @angular/core@"^17.3.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"17.3.9" from @angular/animations@17.3.9
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/animations
npm ERR!     @angular/animations@"^17.3.0" from the root project
npm ERR!     peerOptional @angular/animations@"17.3.9" from @angular/platform-browser@17.3.9
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/platform-browser
npm ERR!       @angular/platform-browser@"^17.3.0" from the root project
npm ERR!       3 more (@angular/forms, @angular/platform-browser-dynamic, @angular/router)
npm ERR!     1 more (ngx-spinner)
npm ERR!   10 more (@angular/common, @angular/compiler, @angular/forms, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! @angular/service-worker@"^17.3.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/core@17.3.12
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"17.3.12" from @angular/service-worker@17.3.12
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/service-worker
npm ERR!     @angular/service-worker@"^17.3.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.


No idea what is in you lock file, but try to update your ng dependencies manually to 17.3.9 before adding the pwa package.

You may view the lock file here in my repo

Okay, so I think I've already resolved the problem. This is how the package.json looks like.
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node -r dotenv/config envPopulator.js && ng serve -o",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^17.3.12",
    "@angular/common": "^17.3.12",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.3.12",
    "@angular/core": "^17.3.12",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.3.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.3.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.3.12",
    "@angular/router": "^17.3.12",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^17.3.12",
    "@tsparticles/angular": "^3.0.0",
    "@tsparticles/engine": "^3.4.0",
    "@tsparticles/slim": "^3.4.0",
    "@types/dom-to-image": "^2.6.7",
    "angularx-qrcode": "^17.0.1",
    "canvas-confetti": "^1.9.3",
    "dom-to-image": "^2.6.0",
    "dom-to-image-more": "^3.3.0",
    "driver.js": "^1.3.1",
    "ngx-spinner": "^17.0.0",
    "primeflex": "^3.3.1",
    "primeicons": "^7.0.0",
    "primeng": "^17.18.4",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.7.5",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^17.3.4",
    "@angular/cli": "^17.3.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.3.12",
    "@types/canvas-confetti": "^1.6.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "@types/uuid": "^10.0.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "jasmine-core": "~5.1.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.4.2"
  }
}

I manually modified some of the dependencies from ^17.3.0 to ^17.3.12, then deleted my node_modules folder using rm -rf node_modules. Finally, I reinstalled all the dependencies with npm install and then tried to add the PWA.
$ ng add @angular/pwa
ℹ Using package manager: npm
✔ Found compatible package version: @angular/pwa@17.3.8.
✔ Package information loaded.

The package @angular/pwa@17.3.8 will be installed and executed.
Would you like to proceed? Yes
✔ Packages successfully installed.
CREATE ngsw-config.json (667 bytes)
CREATE src/manifest.webmanifest (1395 bytes)
CREATE src/assets/icons/icon-128x128.png (2875 bytes)
CREATE src/assets/icons/icon-144x144.png (3077 bytes)
CREATE src/assets/icons/icon-152x152.png (3293 bytes)
CREATE src/assets/icons/icon-192x192.png (4306 bytes)
CREATE src/assets/icons/icon-384x384.png (11028 bytes)
CREATE src/assets/icons/icon-512x512.png (16332 bytes)
CREATE src/assets/icons/icon-72x72.png (1995 bytes)
CREATE src/assets/icons/icon-96x96.png (2404 bytes)
UPDATE angular.json (5497 bytes)
UPDATE package.json (1679 bytes)
UPDATE src/app/app.module.ts (6077 bytes)
UPDATE src/index.html (1838 bytes)
✔ Packages installed successfully.

